# Requirements for eddystone endpoint url

Tags: eddystone, eddystone-url

Are there any requirements for the webpage used as an eddystone URL?

I'm having issues getting an eddystone to broadcast a particular URL (sorry I can't share the URL). It's on https and its a .co TLD, should that make any difference?
If I change the URL to a page on our website (.co.uk) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A URL ending with .co should work.

Two possibilities:

1. For Google Chrome to display a URL, **the URL must actually resolve to a real web page** (it does a validation).  If the .co.uk URL you mention exists but the .co does not, then this might be the issue.
2. **The problem might be with either the encoder or the decoder**.   When you set a URL, it gets encoded into a binary format by the beacon configuration utility and then decoded by the detector app.  One of these sides might have a bug that is causing this to fail when using a ".co" address.  To figure out which is the problem, try using a different detector app like Locate: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8  If it can detect the beacon and the URL looks correct, then the problem may be with the detector side.  Otherwise, it may be with the configuration app.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late perhaps, but there is an online Eddystone link validator:
[verify.physical-web.org](http://verify.physical-web.org)